# Hiding class of a div, when a child div has the specific class name

Tags: jquery, shopify, trustpilot

What I'm generally trying to do is, detect if our product from Trustpilot Widget has 0 reviews, and if it is, show another widget from Trustpilot that shows the number of reviews for our service instead.

Right now, I'm stuck in trying to hide the widget when there's a div class called "tp-stars--0" found on the page.

Here's what I got so far

```
        $('.trustpilot-widget' ).ready(function() {
          if($('.tp-widget-stars').find('.tp-stars.tp-stars--0').length) {
            $('#tp-widget-wrapper').removeClass('visible');
          }
        });
```

```
  <div id="tp-widget-wrapper" class="tp-widget-wrapper visible">
      <div id="wrapper-company-stars" class="wrapper-company-stars">
        <!-- Stars -->
        <div id="tp-widget-stars" class="tp-widget-stars">
           <div class="">
             <div class="tp-stars tp-stars--0">
               <div style="position: relative; height: 0; width: 100%; 
                 padding: 0; padding-bottom: 18.326693227091635%;">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
        <div class="tp-widget-readmore" id="numberOfReviews"><strong>No 
         reviews</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from the element and find the parent.

```
$('.tp-stars--0').parent('#tp-widget-wrapper').removeClass('visible');
```

Comment: `.parent()`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `each` loop on the element and using `closest` to get the parent.

```
    $('.tp-widget-stars').find('.tp-stars.tp-stars--0').each(function() {
       if ($(this).length) {
         $(this).closest('#tp-widget-wrapper').removeClass('visible');
       }
    });
```